# jQuery - Updating a property of a $.data() object

Tags: jquery

Let's say I stored a object/function as data in an element using jQuery

```
function Person() {
    this.age = 17;
    this.gender = 'female';
}

$.data( $('.some-random-element'), 'personDetails', new Person());
```

Let's say that I want to change the age to 18 for that given element. How would go about doing that?

Do I do it like...

```
$('.some-random-element').data('personDetails').age = 18;
```

Or...

```
$('.some-random-element').data('personDetails', $.extend( $('.some-random-element').data('personDetails'), { age : 18 } ));
```

...or is the best and most efficient solution none of the above?

I am confused because I am not sure if `$('.some-random-element').data('personDetails')` returns by reference or value.

Comment: `$.data( $('.some-random-element')`.... wrong. [this syntax requires](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) PURE dom element.... you might want `$("...").data(...)`

Comment: ^ indeed it does, and you'd do it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3C3tv/**

Comment: ^^ and agreed, why use `$.data` with a jQuery collection at all, use `$('element').data()` instead

Comment: ^^^ `$('.some-random-element').data('personDetails').age = 18;` is more natural way to do it. The second is way too verbose and doesn't buy you anything at all unless you want to update several properties at once.

Comment: @dsfq so does it return a reference then? That when I access `$('.some-random-element').data('personDetails').age` I should get 18?

Comment: yes it does - why don't you just try it?

Comment: I tried this  `// foo is initially set to true  
    console.info( $(this).data(pluginDataName) );
    $(this).data(pluginDataName).foo = false;
    console.info( $(this).data(pluginDataName) );`
  
but looking at the output, it didn't seem to change